# Unity C# capsule collider and rigid body don't trigger using transform.position to move

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 simple capsules.  1 is stationary and the other is moving to the same tile on the tilemap using transform.position.

Both capsules have capsule colliders and rigid bodies.  I've attempted to remove the rigid body but from what I can tell, the OnCollisionEnter function requires a rigid body to work.

My script, attached to both of these, is a simple:

```cs
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    print("Collision Detected! " + other.gameObject.name);
}
```

I've used combinations of 'isKinematic', 'isTrigger', placing one component before the other then reversing, ensuring I have the script attached to both objects, making sure my capsule collider is sized to the object, and looked at other people's issues to try their steps to fix my issue.

Nothing seems to trigger the collision between the 2 capsules.  It's got to be something small I'm missing.

I have a tag on both objects and have tried things like `if(other.gameObject.tag == "myTag") {...}` but that's not working for me, either.

Can anyone spot my mistake?  Let me know if you need to see anything else - happy to provide images or whatever will help.  Thanks in advance!

[image: My Hierarchy]

[image: Capsule Mesh Components]

Above is the basic identical hierarchy of both capsules with components attached to the capsule mesh.  Both have the parent empty objects they're stationed under.  (Which themselves, contain scripts but no collider or rigid body)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [`infographic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) to show when a collision message will be detected by [`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) between two objects. Both objects will need some sort of collider, and will most likely need a `Rigidbody`.

[image: Collision Matrix]

You will not want to set `isTrigger` as that will not make it physically react to a collision, but will just detect when a collision occurs. It will also not call `OnCollisionEnter` but will call `OnTriggerEnter`. Setting both not as triggers, adding a collider, and giving them `Rigidbodies` should allow the collision to be detected. You will also need to attach this script to one of the objects that have the collider. Are there other components on the objects you are using?

Comment: I'll add the images above in my post as an edit.

Comment: Both of my capsules have a capsule collider and a rigidbody collider on capsule mesh.  The parent is an empty game object with a couple of scripts attached in both cases as well.  I don't need any physics to happen or gravity or anything... just simple detection that the collision occurred so I can run a function.  (In this case, print to the console or even Debug.Log to the console just for a start)

Comment: As you directed - I've set both not as triggers (isTrigger = false), added a collider, and gave both a rigid body with the script attached - I'm still not able to get the objects to detect the collision.  I can create a short video with a link, if that would be helpful?

Comment: As silly as it might sound - resetting Unity fixed the issue.  Thank you - your answer was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not looking for

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collision collision){}
```